# iOS Accounts Framework -- How to prompt user who hasn't entered account info to do so?

Tags: ios, social-networking, acaccountstore

I am trying to get the Accounts Framework to give me a user's twitter handle.
This works if the user had previously logged on to twitter with their iPhone.

However, if they have never associated their account with their iPhone, I can't find a good way to prompt them to do so.

The method ACAccountStore.renewCredentialsForAccount does take them to settings to re-enter their password, but I don't see a way to take them to that settings screen to enter a new account.

Answer (score 0):

**As to me, the best solution for you right now** is to make an UIAlert that tells something like:

"Please go to your Settings > Twitter and login...thanks"

As currently there is no URL to Twitter/Facebook settings page in iOS.

The only settings page in iOS Settings you can open from your app — is your app's settings page.

You can do that by calling:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString))
```